# Switching between two tabs nested screens using go router

Tags: flutter-go-router

I have a Flutter app that is using go_router.

Suppose that I have two tabs, tabA and tabB. Both tabs are StatefulShellRoute.
TabA has ScreenA1 nested inside it. While TabB has ScreenB1 nested inside it. Nested inside ScreenB1 is ScreenB2.

So we have:

TabA->ScreenA1
TabB->ScreenB1->ScreenB2

Suppose that I am currently standing at ScreenB2.  If I want to navigate to ScreenA1, I can use context.go('/TabA/ScreenA1');

But let us say that I popped screenA1, I will end up in TabA, which is expected.  But if I tab on TabB, I will see ScreenB2. So the question is how do I see TabB and not ScreenB2?

Any idea?